# use api info and equal it to an array

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have a json that i fetched from an api and pass it as props to a child component,i want use the data inside the json and loop through api, then set the data to an array like this:

```
    var myArray = [
{name : name-1, value: value-1}
{name : name-2, value: value-2}
              .
              .
              .
]
```

my api is like this:

```
[
{name : name-1, value:value-1, id:id-1, ... }
                     .
                     .
                     .
]
```

i know if i want return jsx i must use 'map' but what about this situation?

thank you

Comment: So, do you just want to grab `name` and `value` properties?

Comment: Ok then, you can use @Volodymyr's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` function here also:

```js
 var dataFromAPI = [
  {name : 'name-1', value: 'value-1', id: 1},
  {name : 'name-2', value: 'value-2', id: 2},
  {name : 'name-3', value: 'value-3', id: 3},
];

var myArray = dataFromAPI.map(function (data) {
  return {
    name: data.name,
    value: data.value
  };
});

console.log(myArray);
```

or using ES6 syntax:

```js
const dataFromAPI = [
  {name : 'name-1', value: 'value-1', id: 1},
  {name : 'name-2', value: 'value-2', id: 2},
  {name : 'name-3', value: 'value-3', id: 3},
];

const myArray = dataFromAPI.map(({name, value}) => ({ name, value }));

console.log(myArray);
```